# Почему не передаётся массив в функцию через указатель по ссылке (ссылочный указатель)?

Tags: c++, массивы, функции, указатели, ссылки

Почему данная запись не работает?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void foo(int *&pa){}

int main()
{
    int a[4]{};
    foo(a);
}
```

А когда я записываю так, то всё работает. В двух случаях же адрес указателя пытаюсь передать (значение указателя), т.е. сам указатель, в функцию, не создавая при этом новый, а просто ссылаясь на тот указатель. Имя массива может же служить указателем на его первый элемент, т.е. может хранить адрес первого элемента массива. Просто в первом случае я пропустил промежуточный указатель, т.к. имя массива тоже может служить им, но программа поломалась. Адрес то тот же передаю в функцию.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void foo(int *&pa){}

int main()
{
    int a[4]{};
    int *x = a;
    foo(x);
}
```

Кстати, если создать динамический массив `int *a = new int[4];` и потом передать `a` в функцию, то это тоже будет работать, что логично и работает адекватно.
Интересует именно c++.

Comment: *"Имя массива может же служить указателем на его первый элемент, т.е. может хранить адрес первого элемента массива."* - нет, массив в подходящем контексте может быть преобразован в указатель на первый элемент, при этом создается временный объект-указатель. А lvalue ссылка не может биндится ко временному объекту, оттого и первый случай не работает.

Comment: @user7860670 Почему в первом случае имя массива не обрабатывается как указатель?

Comment: С чего вы взяли, что не обрабатывается. Ошибка-то не вы этом.

Comment: @user7860670 Я то передаю имя массива, а оно по идее должно обработаться как указатель на первый элемент массива, вообщем, как обычный указатель во втором случае, а оно выдаёт ошибку.

Comment: *"оно по идее должно обработаться как указатель на первый элемент массива, вообщем, как обычный указатель во втором случае"* - я же уже написал, нет, массив в подходящем контексте может быть преобразован в указатель на первый элемент, при этом создается временный объект-указатель. А имя массива - это ни разу не указатель. Собственно и ошибка не в преобразовании массива в указатель, а в биндинге ссылки.

Comment: Мне кажется вам стоит почитать книги/мануалы, а не спрашивать здесь. Будет быстрее. Сейчас мы ходим кругами... Про то, что указатель, получающийся из массива неявным преобразованием, это (грубо говоря) временный объект, я в каком-то ответе уже вам писал. Про то, что неконстантные lvalue-ссылки можно инициализировать только lvalue - тоже писал...

Comment: Если вы не понимаете ответы, которые вам дают, то скорее всего вы не знаете использованных в них терминов/слов. Любое непонятное (или не полностью понятное) слово или термин надо гуглить.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Вроде разобрался. Сейчас только вопрос глубокого понимания разницы r-value и l-value ссылок остался. Сами термины знаю. Просто смесь разных ссылок и к тому же разные  неявные преобразования, которые просто нужно знать, путают.

Comment: Разница только в том, чем их можно инициализировать (lvalue против rvalue), и больше не в чем. А чтобы понять зачем такая разница - надо читать про move semantics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При преобразовании массива в указатель на его первый элемент, указатель вычисляется на лету и не существует в памяти до преобразования.

Указатель, получающийся в результате преобразования - rvalue (prvalue, если точнее). Грубо говоря это временный объект (хотя формально prvalue - вообще не объекты).

А неконстантные lvalue-ссылки можно инициализировать только lvalue. Отсюда ошибка.

Answer (score -1):

В объявлении `void foo(int *&pa){}` функция `foo()` принимает в качестве параметра ссылку на указатель, т.е. на переменную в памяти, содержащую адрес массива. А в первом случае у вас нет этой переменной, вы пытаетесь передать непосредственный адрес массива, на который нельзя ссылаться по причине его физического отсутствия в памяти. По-этому и не работает.

Попытаюсь расширить объяснение: по ссылке в теле функции `foo()` вы можете изменить значение переданного указателя. Например:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int b[5];

void foo(int *&pa)
{
    pa = b; //изменяем указатель по ссылке
}

int main()
{
    int a[4]{};
    int* p = a; 

    //сейчас p содержит адрес a
    foo(p);
    //а сейчас p содержит адрес b

    //а этот вызов не имеет смысла:
   foo(a);
   //...так как a - это непосредственный адрес массива a[], вы не можете его менять.
}
```

Как-то так.

P.S. И что тут кому не понравилось в моём объяснении??

Comment: Ага, т.е. нельзя передавать временные объекты через указатель по ссылке. И вот эта фраза может это впринципе объяснить `//...так как a - это непосредственный адрес массива a[], вы не можете его менять.`

Comment: @Kosmp рад, если мой ответ прояснил ваш вопрос

Comment: Адрес **статического** массива, его первого элемента изменить же никак нельзя? Вот поэтому язык, наверное, устроен так, что не даёт передать подобный временный указатель в функцию через ссылочный указатель

Comment: @Kosmp изменить вы можете значение переменной или элемента массива, но не прямой адрес этой переменной или массива в памяти. Так, переменная типа `int* p` содержит адрес другой переменной типа `int`, либо адрес массива элементов типа `int`. Этот адрес есть значение переменной `p`, по-этому вы можете его менять. А вот на расположение самого статического массива `int a[]` в памяти вы повлиять не можете, что в общем-то логично.

Comment: @Kosmp и да, любые правила и ограничения компилятора строго логически обоснованы. Вам тут правильно написали про временные указатели и что на них нельзя ссылаться, я же постарался объяснить, чем это обоснованно с позиции логики. Во всех на первый взгляд непонятных вещах старайтесь понять логику, и тогда большинство вопросов будут отпадать автоматически.